# Template partial specialization and multiple compilation units

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I am having trouble getting consistent behavior out of different compilers for this code and am trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong.  The basic setup has a template class (Printer), a partial specialization (for the odd value integers) which adds a static const member.  The problem arises when I attempt to define that static const member in various different ways.

I've reduced the code to three files.  To answer an immediate question I'm avoiding c++11, so I provide a custom enable_if template.

File "template_bug.h"

```
template<bool B, class T = void> struct my_enable_if          {};
template<        class T       > struct my_enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

template< int Value, typename = void > struct Printer {
    static void doIt() { std::cout << "Printer<" << Value << "(even)>::doIt()" << std::endl; }
};

template< int Value > struct Printer< Value, typename my_enable_if<Value & 1>::type > {
    static const char *c_prefix;
    static void doIt() { std::cout << "Printer<" << c_prefix << Value << "(odd)>::doIt()" << std::endl; }
};

template<> const char *Printer<1>::c_prefix = "One_";
```

File "other.cc":

```
#include <iostream>
#include "template_bug.h"

template<> const char *Printer<5>::c_prefix = "Five_";
```

File "main.cc":

```
#include <iostream>
#include "template_bug.h"

template<> const char *Printer<3>::c_prefix = "Three_";

int main(void)
{
    Printer<1>::doIt();
    Printer<3>::doIt();
    Printer<5>::doIt();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, my understanding is that this code should compile and doesn't invoke any undefined behavior, but I feel like I must be wrong somehow.  When I compile this in g++ (4.8.4):

```
g++ -c -o main.cc.o main.cc
g++ -c -o other.cc.o other.cc
g++ -o template_bug main.cc.o other.cc.o
```

I get this during the link phase:

```
other.cc.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `Printer<1, void>::c_prefix'
main.cc.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
```

I was of the impression that this symbol should have weak linkage specifically to avoid this error.

**Question 1**: Why is `Printer<1>::c_prefix` not a weak symbol (under g++)?

If I comment out the `Printer<1>` usages, the rest compiles, links, and executes as expected.

---

On a different compiler (Greenhills) The error that I get is:

```
[elxr] (error #412) unresolved symbols: 1
 Printer<N1, my_enable_if<(bool)(N1&((int)1)), void>::type>::c_prefix [with N1=(int)5]     from main.o
```

The root cause is that the compiler has chosen to generate differing symbol names between the two compilation units.  Using nm I can see the differences:

From nm other.o:

```
00000000 D c_prefix__S__94Printer__ps__63_XZ1ZQ2_48my_enable_if__tm__28_XOcsb_1_Oad_2_Z1ZCiL_1_1OOv4type__tm__9_XCiL_1_5
```

From nm main.o:

```
         U c_prefix__94Printer__ps__63_XZ1ZQ2_48my_enable_if__tm__28_XOcsb_1_Oad_2_Z1ZCiL_1_1OOv4type__tm__9_XCiL_1_5
```

After exchanging several emails with their support I'm being told that my code is invoking UB, but their explanation for why this is UB doesn't make sense.

**Question 2**: Is anything about the `Printer<5>` usage invoking undefined behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 2: Is anything about the `Printer<5>` usage invoking undefined behavior?

Specialization has to be declared before to use it, else the program is ill formed (no diagnostic required).

So the correct way would be:

File "template_bug.h"

```
template<bool B, class T = void> struct my_enable_if          {};
template<        class T       > struct my_enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

template< int Value, typename = void > struct Printer {
    static void doIt() {
        std::cout << "Printer<" << Value << "(even)>::doIt()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template< int Value > struct Printer< Value, typename my_enable_if<Value & 1>::type > {
    static const char *c_prefix;
    static void doIt() {
        std::cout << "Printer<" << c_prefix << Value << "(odd)>::doIt()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<> const char *Printer<1>::c_prefix; // Declaration
template<> const char *Printer<3>::c_prefix; // Declaration

// or since C++17, inline static variable.
template<> inline const char *Printer<5>::c_prefix = "Five_";
```

And in a cpp (might be split into several cpp, but just one definition):

```
template<> const char *Printer<1>::c_prefix = "One_";   // Definition
template<> const char *Printer<3>::c_prefix = "Three_"; // Definition
```

Comment: Worth noting that in C++17 you can declare variables `inline` just like functions, so with GCC 7 or above you _can_ define the specializations in the header.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what counts as a declaration for c_prefix.  Why does the existence of the declaration in the partial specialization not count as a declaration?  Is it not considered a declaration because it's not fully specialized?  It seems to define all of the properties of the symbol, so I'm not certain what the added lines (in the header) provide that is missing without those lines.

Comment: In your sample, You declare (generic) `Printer<odd>::c_prefix` without definition. You define also (in "unrelated" cpp) `Printer<5>::c_prefix`. `Printer<5>::c_prefix` is different than `Printer<odd>::c_prefix`. From `main`, `Printer<5>::doIt();` would use the generic odd `c_prefix` (specialization is unknown).

Comment: `template<int V> const char *Printer<V, my_enable_if<V&1>::type>::c_prefix = "foo";` 1) That would count as a definition for what you've described as `Printer<odd>::c_prefix`?  2) For that code to exist in any compilation unit, it must exist in all compilation units prior to the first instantiation of any Printer<odd> variant? 3) Violating that would itself be UB? 4) In it's absence the Printer<odd> instantiation should, therefore, assume that an explicit full specialization exists somewhere, shouldn't it? 5) It definitely shouldn't be expecting something that would, by definition, be UB?

Comment: Yes, lazy to type the whole SFINAE. Definition count as declaration, so your `Printer<3>` is ok. and declaration of specialization should be used before it usage (we might know if generic or specialization has to be chosen). That error cannot be known at compile time, only possibly at link time.

Comment: "we might know if generic or specialization has to be chosen" This is the crux of my confusion.  My belief is that we definitely know that the specialization should be chosen in main.cc where `Printer<5>` is  implicitly instantiated.  If the generic were intended it would be UB for the definition above (or at least the declaration of the same form) to not have already been observed by the compiler.  It's absence should be sufficient to establish it's nonexistence.

Answer (score 4):

Note there are actually two variations of the One Definition Rule.

Some things (roughly what we tend to put in source files) may only be defined once in the entire program:

- non-inline namespace scope variables
- non-inline `static` class data members
- non-inline functions
- template explicit specializations which define any of the above
- template explicit instantiations

Other things with external linkage (roughly what we tend to put in header files) may be defined multiple times in different translation units, as long as all definitions contain the same tokens and have the same meaning:

- inline namespace scope variables (in C++17 and later)
- inline `static` class data members (in C++17 and later)
- inline functions (including functions defined inside a class definition)
- all types, including `class`, `struct`, `union`, `enum`, and `typedef`/`using` definitions
- template explicit specializations which define any of the above
- primary templates
- class template partial specializations
- template deduction guides

(Neither ODR applies to namespaces.)

In C++14 and earlier, every explicit specialization of a `static` class data member falls into the first category.  And since `#include` essentially inserts all the tokens from a header file into your translation unit, putting that explicit specialization in the header and therefore both translation units is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

So in C++14 or earlier, you would need to move that explicit specialization definition to a source file.  But you should also declare all your explicit specializations in the header file, as soon as possible after the class template partial specialization:

```
template<> const char *Printer<1>::c_prefix;
template<> const char *Printer<3>::c_prefix;
template<> const char *Printer<5>::c_prefix;
```

In C++17 and later, though, we have the option of inline variables and inline `static` class data members.  So if you want to keep the explicit specialization definition in the header for some reason, you can just make it inline:

```
template<> inline const char *Printer<1>::c_prefix = "One_";
```

(By the way, your code leaves it possible to change the `c_prefix` pointers to point at something else. If you don't want this, consider changing the type from `const char*` to `const char* const`.)

Comment: Ok, so the answer to Q1 is basically "don't do that because you can't avoid violating ODR" pre-c++17, and "add an inline to avoid ODR violation" for c++17 and beyond.  Thanks for pointing out the mutability, it was an oversight in this reduced version.

Answer (score 2):

> I was of the impression that this symbol should have weak linkage
>   specifically to avoid this error.

Where did you get this impression?

> Question 1: Why is Printer<1>::c_prefix not a weak symbol (under g++)?

Again, why would it be?

> Now, my understanding is that this code should compile and doesn't
>   invoke any undefined behavior

You are violating the ODR. The definition of `Printer<1>::c_prefix` should appear only in one compilation unit because it is a full specialization.

```
template<> const char *Printer<1>::c_prefix = "One_";
```

You either confusing concepts (maybe weak linkage with inline definitions) or have a misunderstanding somewhere. Weak linkage is a **implementation** ABI detail for the ELF format. In gcc you need to explicitly adnotate symbols you want to have weak linkage. Your code has nothing to do with *weak linkage* or *weak symbols* whatsoever.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the declaration can reside in the header, to let other compilation units know there is a specialization somewhere.

Comment: I find this funny as this is exactly what greenhills wants me to do to resolve the issue on their compiler...push the definition into the shared header.

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important thing - It is an explicit specialization. Otherwise there is no violation of ODR rule.

Comment: working on improving the answer. Making sure I don't say untrue things...

Comment: @super This is not the problem here. It's about explicit specialization. Otherwise you **can** put the definition in the header.

Comment: @liliscent I know that's not the problem here, but I still think it's worth mentioning. Especially in this context.

Comment: Your guess was correct in the conflation of weak linkage and inline in my head.  As mentioned elsewhere C++17 allows the insertion of "inline" in my definition which, I'm fairly certain would be handled in ELF implementations by marking these symbols as weak.  I had assumed this was already the default behavior (for templated statics).